# Query on all columns cassandra

Tags: cassandra, database-schema

I have close to six tables, each of them have from 20 to 60 columns in Cassandra. I am designing the schema for this database.

The requirement from the query is that all the columns must be queriable individually.

- I know if the data has High-Cardinality using secondary indexes is not encouraged.
- Materialized views will solve my purpose to an extent where I will be able to query on other columns as well.

My question is : 
In this scenario, if each table has 30 to 50+ materialized views, is this an okay pattern to follow or is it going on a totally wrong track. Is it taking this functionality to its extreme. Maybe writes will start to become expensive on the system (I know they are written eventually and not with the immediate write to the actual table).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely do not want 30 to 50 materialized views.

It sounds like the use case you're trying to satisfy is search, more so than a specific query.

If the queries that are going to be done on each column can be pre defined, then you can also go the denormalization route, trading flexibility of search for better performance and less operational overhead.

If you're interested in the search route, here's what I suggest you take a look at:

- [SASI Indexes](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058) (depending on Cassandra version you're using)
- [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/)
- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [DataStax Enterprise Search](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-search) (disclaimer I work for DataStax)
- [Elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra)
- [Stratio](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index)

Those are just the ones I know off the top of my head. There may be others (Sorry if I missed you). I provided links to each so you can make your own informed decision as to which makes more sense for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @MarcintheCloud -- its great when someone from DataStax answers your question in the first few mins of asking the question. : )  -- Make Stakoverflow great again! ; p